# Using loops to find the highest score, lowest score from a list

Tags: python

Update: It seems that I understood the directions for the code wrong.

Absolutely new to Python, so any help is appreciated.

I am trying to find the highest score and the lowest score from an array using loops.

Here is the code I worked on:

```
nums = [6, 8, 9, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3]
highest_score = []
lowest_score = []

def calculate_Scores(nums):
  i = 1
  max = min = nums[0]
  if nums[0] > nums[1]:
    highest_score.append(nums[0])
  elif nums[0] < nums[1]:
    lowest_score.append(nums[0])
  while i < len(nums):
    if nums[i] > max:
      highest_score.append(nums[i])
    if nums[i] < min:
      lowest_score.append(nums[i])
    i += 1

 calculate_Scores(nums)
 print(highest_score)
 print(lowest_score)
```

Output:

```
 [8, 9] #highest
 [6, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3] #lowest
```

The code works just fine for the array given above,  but when you change the array nums to:

```
[2, 8, 9, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3]
```

This is the output:

```
[8, 9, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3] #highest
[2] #lowest
```

How can I make it work so that 3 also goes to the variable lowest_score?
Is there any other way I can make this whole process work? (Without using max() and min())

Comment: Why are you making `highest_score` and `lowest_score` lists? Why not just make them numbers, and replace them every time you get a larger value? As it is, you're just sorting numbers based on whether they're greater or less than the first element.

Comment: What is the logic for determining highest and lowest? Typically there is one value that is lowest, and one that is highest.

Comment: I get the point you are making. I basically am reading numbers from a text file, the text files contain scores from different teams. The scores are to be updated after the user inputs new scores. Here is the direction I am trying to follow: "In fact, you can use a loop, in each iteration of the loop, you read one number from the file, compare it with the current highest/lowest score and update the highest/lowest if needed."

Comment: From the instructions you shared, it sounds like the highest and lowest scores are numbers, not lists.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Can you please elaborate??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to find the highest number, why do you append to `highest_score` or `lowest_score` constantly? Wouldn't you want to only append the maximum or minimum? Why not calculate them first?

```
nums = [6, 8, 9, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3]
highest_score = []
lowest_score = []

def calculate_Scores(nums):
  i = 1
  max = min = nums[0]
  # first, calculate the max and min.
  while i < len(nums):  # (possible improvement: replace this with a for loop)
    if nums[i] > max:
      max = nums[i]    # replace max with the new max
    if nums[i] < min:
      min = nums[i]    # replace min with the new min
    i += 1
  # now that you've done that, add them to the highest_score and lowest_score
  highest_score.append(max)
  lowest_score.append(min)
```

Note that while this may be a useful educational exercise, there's no practical reason to not just use the built-in functions `max()` and `min()` in this situation (or really any other situation where you're trying to find the one element that out-competes others in some way).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It seems that I did not understood the directions properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do it. If you want to use a `for` loop:

```
nums = [6, 8, 9, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3]
highest_number = 0

for n in nums:
    if n > highest_score:
        highest_score = n
print(highest_number)
```

Or there is a built in function called `max()` which will do the same:

```
print(max(nums)) # outputs 9
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
student_scores = input('Enter all scores at once, leaving a single space between each!').split()

for n in range(0, len(student_scores)):
    student_scores[n] = int(student_scores[n])
    
    
    highest_number = 0
    
    
for n in student_scores:
    if n > highest_number:
            highest_number = n
print(highest_number)
```

Comment: This question and its accepted answer are both over three years old. It's fine to answer old questions, but it's usually a good idea to explain how your answer differs from what's already here. How is this better than the other approach?